# export a csv file from the database with a cronjob

Tags: php, wp-cron, cron, curl

I'm using an event plugin, which doesn't have a user-friendly function for showing a list of bookings. That's why I wrote a php+js script myself to display that data in a nice way.
But to use my own script I need the booking data from the wp database.

The MEC-plugin gives me an option to export this booking data in csv format from the admin dashboard. But I want to use this export as a cronjob, but have the hardest time to get this to work.

I tried to use this export link (/wp-admin/admin.php?page=MEC-ix&tab=MEC-export&mec-ix-action=export-bookings&format=csv) as an url in my cronjob php but I always get the login page as a return.

Is there a method to run this cronjob from within WP as admin so I don't have to login anymore?
Or do I need to figure out how to login with cURL to WP to make this cronjob work?

Or are there even better/easier methodes to do something like this?

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: Please check [for login with cURL in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728274/php-curl-post-to-login-to-wordpress#:~:text=%22blog%2Fwordpress%2Fwp%2D,Gecko%2F20070725%20Firefox%2F2.0.)